# string cycle case (lowercase - capitalize - uppercase)

Tags: python

I know how to convert selected text, in python, from lowercase to uppercase and vice-versa: with

```
string.swapcase();
```

and I know how to capitalize selected text: with

```
string.capitalize();
```

but I'd like to get a **cycle** lowercase - *capitalize* - uppercase of selected text.
It's possible with python?

### EDIT

- Capitalized: Text;
- uppercase: TEXT;
- lowercase: text.

### possible solution

```
### Get the current selection.  
sText=clipboard.get_selection()  

### Analyse.  
if sText.islower():  
    sText=sText.capitalize()  
elif sText.isupper():  
    sText=sText.lower()  
else:  
    sText=sText.upper()  

### Send the result.  
keyboard.send_keys(sText)
```

The problem of this solution is that the text not remain *selected*.

Comment: What is the difference between capitalize and uppercase?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including desired input and output, and what you've tried so far

Comment: You can use the `str` methods `isupper()`, `islower()`, and `istitle()` to detect what capitalization style the text already has, and based on that, apply the "next" style in the cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### my first solution

Solved!

```
# Get the current selection.
sText=clipboard.get_selection()
lLength=len(sText)

# Analyse.
if sText.islower():
    sText=sText.capitalize()
elif sText.isupper():
    sText=sText.lower()
else:
    sText=sText.upper()

# Send the result.
keyboard.send_keys(sText)
keyboard.send_keys("<shift>+<left>"*lLength)
```

This works!
*But* the capitalized text is only the first word.

### another, better solution (the mixed case is of *all* the words)

```
# Get the current selection.
sText=clipboard.get_selection()
lLength=len(sText)

try:
    if not store.has_key("textCycle"):
        store.set_value("state","title")

except:
    pass

# get saved value of textCycle
state = store.get_value("textCycle")


# modify text and set next modfication style
if state == "title":
    #sText=sText.capitalize()
    sText=sText.title()
    newstate = "lower"

elif state == "lower":
    sText=sText.lower()
    newstate = "upper"

elif state == "upper":
    sText=sText.upper()
    newstate = "title"

else:
    newstate = "lower"

# save for next run of script
store.set_value("textCycle",newstate)   

# Send the result.
keyboard.send_keys(sText)
keyboard.send_keys("<shift>+<left>"*lLength)
```